# Any idea on how add a custom control for next/previous inside my player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to add the **previous/next track button** (btnNext/btnPrev) Inside my grey player on the **left-side of the play button**. I still did not figure out what I have to do in my Js or in my CSS code to make it work.

I have try adding the custom control but Previous track and next track is not listed

```
[
   'play-large', // The large play button in the center
   'restart', // Restart playback
   'rewind', // Rewind by the seek time (default 10 seconds)
   'play', // Play/pause playback
   'fast-forward', // Fast forward by the seek time (default 10 seconds)
   'progress', // The progress bar and scrubber for playback and buffering
   'current-time', // The current time of playback
   'duration', // The full duration of the media
   'mute', // Toggle mute
   'volume', // Volume control
   'captions', // Toggle captions
   'settings', // Settings menu
   'pip', // Picture-in-picture (currently Safari only)
   'airplay', // Airplay (currently Safari only)
   'download', // Show a download button with a link to either the current source or a custom URL you specify in your options
   'fullscreen', // Toggle fullscreen
];
```

[image: Like in classic audio player]

HAVE A LOOK TO MY FIDDLE: ***http://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/1oL6w5jm/23/***

Precious help to improve my code?

Note:
This audio player features playlist support via JSON data and step navigation. The version you're seeing now is a fresh new take on this project... by modernizing the style and offloading all browser detection crap to a wonderful audio player plugin called Plyr (https://github.com/sampotts/plyr).

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    'use strict'
    var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
    if (supportsAudio) {
        // initialize plyr
        var player = new Plyr('#audio1', {
            controls: [
                'restart',
                'play',
                'progress',
                'current-time',
                'duration',
                'mute',
                'volume',
                'download'
            ]
        });
        // initialize playlist and controls
        var index = 0,
            playing = false,
            mediaPath = 'https://archive.org/download/mythium/',
            extension = '',
            tracks = [{
                "track": 1,
                "name": "All This Is - Joe L.'s Studio",
                "duration": "2:46",
                "file": "JLS_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 2,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "8:30",
                "file": "BS_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 3,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (Final Mix)",
                "duration": "5:01",
                "file": "BS_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 4,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "8:31",
                "file": "BSFM_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 5,
                "name": "All The King's Men - Broadwing Studio (First Mix)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "BSFM_ATKM"
            }, {
                "track": 6,
                "name": "All This Is - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "AC_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 7,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 1) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:44",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 8,
                "name": "All The King's Men (Take 2) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:26",
                "file": "AC_ATKMTake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 9,
                "name": "Magus - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "AC_M"
            }, {
                "track": 10,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address (fucked up) - Alternate Cuts",
                "duration": "5:25",
                "file": "AC_TSOWAfucked_up"
            }, {
                "track": 11,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "5:53",
                "file": "PNY04-05_M"
            }, {
                "track": 12,
                "name": "On The Waterfront - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "4:40",
                "file": "PNY04-05_OTW"
            }, {
                "track": 13,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "13:15",
                "file": "PNY04-05_T"
            }, {
                "track": 14,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "8:12",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 15,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (New Years '04 - '05)",
                "duration": "7:02",
                "file": "PNY04-05_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 16,
                "name": "Magus - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:43",
                "file": "PVD_M"
            }, {
                "track": 17,
                "name": "Trance - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "10:45",
                "file": "PVD_T"
            }, {
                "track": 18,
                "name": "The State Of Wearing Address - Popeye's (Valentine's Day '05)",
                "duration": "5:36",
                "file": "PVD_TSOWA"
            }, {
                "track": 19,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "2:48",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 20,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (01/08/04)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB01_08_04_M"
            }, {
                "track": 21,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "13:07",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_BTPE"
            }, {
                "track": 22,
                "name": "Innocence - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:16",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_I"
            }, {
                "track": 23,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "5:46",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 24,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "4:51",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 25,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (06/06/03)",
                "duration": "8:43",
                "file": "SSB06_06_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 26,
                "name": "All This Is - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "3:00",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ATI"
            }, {
                "track": 27,
                "name": "Magus - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "6:09",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_M"
            }, {
                "track": 28,
                "name": "Madness Explored - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "5:05",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_ME"
            }, {
                "track": 29,
                "name": "Trance - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "12:32",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_T"
            }, {
                "track": 30,
                "name": "The Forsaken - Smith St. Basement (12/28/03)",
                "duration": "8:56",
                "file": "SSB12_28_03_TF"
            }, {
                "track": 31,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "4:55",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 32,
                "name": "All This Is (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "5:45",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_ATITake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 33,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "14:05",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 34,
                "name": "Beneath The Painted Eye (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "13:25",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_BTPETake_2"
            }, {
                "track": 35,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 1) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:37",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_1"
            }, {
                "track": 36,
                "name": "The Forsaken (Take 2) - Smith St. Basement (Nov. '03)",
                "duration": "8:36",
                "file": "SSB___11_03_TFTake_2"
            }],
            buildPlaylist = $.each(tracks, function(key, value) {
                var trackNumber = value.track,
                    trackName = value.name,
                    trackDuration = value.duration;
                if (trackNumber.toString().length === 1) {
                    trackNumber = '0' + trackNumber;
                }
                $('#plList').append('<li> \
                    <div class="plItem"> \
                        <span class="plNum">' + trackNumber + '.</span> \
                        <span class="plTitle">' + trackName + '</span> \
                        <span class="plLength">' + trackDuration + '</span> \
                    </div> \
                </li>');
            }),
            trackCount = tracks.length,
            npAction = $('#npAction'),
            npTitle = $('#npTitle'),
            audio = $('#audio1').on('play', function () {
                playing = true;
                npAction.text('Now Playing...');
            }).on('pause', function () {
                playing = false;
                npAction.text('Paused...');
            }).on('ended', function () {
                npAction.text('Paused...');
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }).get(0),
            btnPrev = $('#btnPrev').on('click', function () {
                if ((index - 1) > -1) {
                    index--;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            btnNext = $('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
            li = $('#plList li').on('click', function () {
                var id = parseInt($(this).index());
                if (id !== index) {
                    playTrack(id);
                }
            }),
            loadTrack = function (id) {
                $('.plSel').removeClass('plSel');
                $('#plList li:eq(' + id + ')').addClass('plSel');
                npTitle.text(tracks[id].name);
                index = id;
                audio.src = mediaPath + tracks[id].file + extension;
                updateDownload(id, audio.src);
            },
            updateDownload = function (id, source) {
                player.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
                    $('a[data-plyr="download"]').attr('href', source);
                });
            },
            playTrack = function (id) {
                loadTrack(id);
                audio.play();
            };
        extension = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? '.mp3' : audio.canPlayType('audio/ogg') ? '.ogg' : '';
        loadTrack(index);
    } else {
        // no audio support
        $('.column').addClass('hidden');
        var noSupport = $('#audio1').text();
        $('.container').append('<p class="no-support">' + noSupport + '</p>');
    }
});
```

```
/* Album thumbnail should display here when track is playing
================================================== */
.flex-container {
    width:70vh;
    //pointer-events:none;
  display:block;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:999999999999;
    position:fixed;
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    //background:black;
}

.track-thumbnails img {
  //transform: rotate(5deg);
  width: 40vh;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.56); 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.56);

}

/* Font Family
================================================== */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300,400,700');


/* Global Styles
================================================== */

html,body {
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
background-color:#0665a2;
color:#fff;
font-size:1rem;
font-family:"Oxygen", HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
letter-spacing:.025rem;
line-height:1.618;
padding:1rem 0;
}

*,::before,::after {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}


/* Setup
================================================== */

.container { position:relative; margin:0 auto; max-width:800px; width:100%; }
.column { width:inherit; }


/* Typography / Links
================================================== */

p { color:#fff; display:block; font-size:.9rem; font-weight:400; margin:0 0 2px; }

a,a:visited { color:#8cc3e6; outline:0; text-decoration:underline; }
a:hover,a:focus { color:#bbdef5; }
p a,p a:visited { line-height:inherit; }


/* Misc.
================================================== */

.add-bottom { margin-bottom:2rem !important; }
.left { float:left; }
.right { float:right; }
.center { text-align:center; }
.hidden { display:none; }

.no-support {
margin:2rem auto;
text-align:center;
width:90%;
}


/* Audio Player Styles
================================================== */

audio {
display:none;
}

#audiowrap,
#plwrap {
margin:0 auto;
}

#tracks {
font-size:0;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

#nowPlay {
display:block;
font-size:0;
}

#nowPlay span {
display:inline-block;
font-size:1.05rem;
vertical-align:top;
}

#nowPlay span#npAction {
padding:21px;
width:30%;
}

#nowPlay span#npTitle {
padding:21px;
text-align:right;
width:70%;
}

#plList li {
cursor:pointer;
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:21px 0;
}

#plList li:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plItem {
position:relative;
}

.plTitle {
left:50px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
right:65px;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
top:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.plNum {
padding-left:21px;
width:25px;
}

.plLength {
padding-left:21px;
position:absolute;
right:21px;
top:0;
}

.plSel,
.plSel:hover {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
cursor:default !important;
}

#tracks a {
border-radius:3px;
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
font-size:2.3rem;
height:35px;
line-height:.175;
margin:0 5px 30px;
padding:10px 15px;
text-decoration:none;
transition:background .3s ease;
}

#tracks a:last-child {
margin-left:0;
}

#tracks a:hover,
#tracks a:active {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
color:#fff;
}

#tracks a::-moz-focus-inner {
border:0;
padding:0;
}


/* Plyr Overrides
================================================== */

.plyr--audio .plyr__controls {
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
color:#fff;
padding:20px 20px 20px 13px;
width:100%;
}

a.plyr__controls__item.plyr__control:hover,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button:hover,
.plyr--audio .plyr__controls button.tab-focus:focus,
.plyr__play-large {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr__progress--played,
.plyr__volume--display {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer,
.plyr--audio .plyr__volume--display {
background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.plyr--audio .plyr__progress--buffer {
color:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}


/* Media Queries
================================================== */

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #nowPlay span#npAction { display:none; }
    #nowPlay span#npTitle { display:block; text-align:center; width:100%; }
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.5.6/plyr.css">





<div class="container">
    <div class="column add-bottom">
        <div id="mainwrap">
            <div id="nowPlay">
                <span id="npAction">Paused...</span><span id="npTitle"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="audiowrap">
                <div id="audio0">
                    <audio id="audio1" preload controls>Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio! </audio>
                </div>
                <div id="tracks">




<div class="flex-container"><div class="track-thumbnails">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20348%20225%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_171d59a550b%20text%20%7B%20fill%3A%23eceeef%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Bfont-family%3AArial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20Open%20Sans%2C%20sans-serif%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A17pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_171d59a550b%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22348%22%20height%3D%22225%22%20fill%3D%22%2355595c%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22116.7109375%22%20y%3D%22120.15%22%3EThumbnail%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
</div></div>






                    <a id="btnPrev">&vltri;</a><a id="btnNext">&vrtri;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="plwrap">
                <ul id="plList"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column add-bottom center">
        <p>Music by <a href="http://www.mythium.net/">Mythium</a></p>
        <p>Download: <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_vbr_mp3.zip">zip</a> / <a href="https://archive.org/download/mythium/mythium_archive.torrent">torrent</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5media/1.1.8/html5media.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.5.6/plyr.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess you check this reported issue =>
https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1227

and this section => https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/CONTROLS.md

Comment: @Jac yes unfortunately... I just need to have my next track inside my player, any hint?

Comment: I did update the comment. Did you check the second link? CONTROLS.md ?

Comment: Many thanks @Jac ... Could you help me directly in my fiddle? Would be so helpful, still new at JSON unfortunately... I have checked inside CONTROLS.md  but still no  trace of preview and next track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to use HTML custom controls to draw your player.
Instead of putting an array of pre made properties try in the suggested way for custom controls. Something like :

```js
const controls = `
<div class="plyr__controls">
    <button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="restart">
        <svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-restart"></use></svg>
        <span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Restart</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="rewind">
        <svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-rewind"></use></svg>
        <span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Rewind {seektime} secs</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="plyr__control" aria-label="Play, {title}" data-plyr="play">
        <svg class="icon--pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-pause"></use></svg>
        <svg class="icon--not-pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-play"></use></svg>
        <span class="label--pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Pause</span>
        <span class="label--not-pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Play</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="plyr__control" data-plyr="fast-forward">
        <svg role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-fast-forward"></use></svg>
        <span class="plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Forward {seektime} secs</span>
    </button>
    <div class="plyr__progress">
        <input data-plyr="seek" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" aria-label="Seek">
        <progress class="plyr__progress__buffer" min="0" max="100" value="0">% buffered</progress>
        <span role="tooltip" class="plyr__tooltip">00:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="plyr__time plyr__time--current" aria-label="Current time">00:00</div>
    <div class="plyr__time plyr__time--duration" aria-label="Duration">00:00</div>
    <button type="button" class="plyr__control" aria-label="Mute" data-plyr="mute">
        <svg class="icon--pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-muted"></use></svg>
        <svg class="icon--not-pressed" role="presentation"><use xlink:href="#plyr-volume"></use></svg>
        <span class="label--pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Unmute</span>
        <span class="label--not-pressed plyr__tooltip" role="tooltip">Mute</span>
    </button>
    <div class="plyr__volume">
        <input data-plyr="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" autocomplete="off" aria-label="Volume">
    </div>

</div>
`;

var player = new Plyr('#audio1', { controls });
```

This is just a copy and paste of what the author put in the documentation.
You can copy this bit in your fiddle where you initialize your player, it seems exactly what you were looking for.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5kfgbctu/

You already wrote the logic to skip tracks:

```js
            btnNext = $('#btnNext').on('click', function () {
                if ((index + 1) < trackCount) {
                    index++;
                    loadTrack(index);
                    if (playing) {
                        audio.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                    index = 0;
                    loadTrack(index);
                }
            }),
```

You can reuse that logic with the buttons in the example above.

Comment: @Thanks Jac, it works but the next and previous track is still outside the player unfortunately :( You have any idea of how I could fix this?  ___________________________________________I just want to place out the rewind and forward of 10sec and place previous and next track instead

Comment: They are outside the track because they are still in the html, I didn't change your html.
You have to delete 

   <a id="btnPrev">&vltri;</a><a id="btnNext">&vrtri;</a>

Comment: You are welcome. If what I wrote solved your problem, you might want to set it as accepted answer to help someone else to fix the same scenario.